# set some validations on text_field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a `text_field` that I want set 3 `validation` on this. In this `text_field` I get reporter's phone number. Each reporter `has_one` `reporterprofile`. I want when reporter enter his phone_number, I check `validates_numericality_of` and `validates_length_of` and if these two are true, then check `uniqueness validation`, If this `phone_number` is new, thats ok, I create a `reporterprofile` and `redirect_to` `reporterprofile` by this new `id`, But if this `phone_number` is exist, I want page is `redirect_to` this `reporterprofile` without created new reporter.

`reporter.rb`

```
class Reporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reporterprofile
  before_create :build_reporterprofile

  validates :phone_number, uniqueness: true

  validates_numericality_of :phone_number
  validates_length_of :phone_number, :minimum => 11, :maximum => 11
end
```

`reporters_controller.rb`

```
def create
    @reporter = Reporter.new(reporter_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reporter.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_reporterprofile_path(:id => @reporter.reporterprofile), notice: 'Reporter was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @reporter }
      else
        if
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @reporter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I can `redirect_to edit_reporterprofile_path` when `reporter` doesn't save, but if I do this, `numerically` and `length` validations are don't check. How can I `redirect` reporter that is exist to his profile?

Comment: What's the error? Your code looks okay to me?

Comment: Code is ok, By this code, if I enter a reporter phone_number that is exist in database, I get this error:`Phone number has already been taken`. But I want if reporter is exist and other validations are ok, page is redirect_to this reporterprofile.

Comment: please be clear while asking questions

Comment: I'm sorry about my week english language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if a Reporter with the given phone number exists. If so, redirect to the reporterprofile path. Otherwise, create the new reporter. There are various ways to organize the logic to handle this. Here it is all shoved into the "create" action of the reporters controller.

```
def create
    existing_reporter = Reporter.includes(:reporterprofile).find_by(phone_number: reporter_params[:phone_number])
    if existing_reporter
      redirect_to reporterprofile_path(existing_reporter.reporterprofile)
    else
      @reporter = Reporter.new(reporter_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @reporter.save
          format.html { redirect_to edit_reporterprofile_path(:id => @reporter.reporterprofile), notice: 'Reporter was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @reporter }
        else
          if
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @reporter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by populating the [`validates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers) method with more than what you've got now. This will remove the dependency on the other two methods you have, which should go to fixing some of the issue:

```
validates :phone_number,
   length: { is: 6 },
   numericality: true,
   uniqueness: true
```